# How to sum nested objects and get a new object in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopback

I have 2 Objects Set_1 and Set_2. Inside their, two key are there in both Key_1 and Key_2. Inside those Key_1 and Key_2, there are Sub Keys(Sub Keys are same for Both Objects) which I want to add and want to create a new Object.

```
  "Set_1": {
  "Key_1": {
    "Sub_Key_1": 110,
    "Sub_Key_2": 72,
    "Sub_Key_3": 182
  },
  "Key_2": {
    "Sub_Key_1": 110,
    "Sub_Key_2": 72,
    "Sub_Key_3": 182
  }
}


"Set_2": {
"Key_1": {
    "Sub_Key_1": 50,
    "Sub_Key_2": 72,
    "Sub_Key_3": 112
},
  "Key_2": {
    "Sub_Key_1": 30,
    "Sub_Key_2": 40,
    "Sub_Key_3": 70
  }
}
```

I want output like below-

```
  "Set_3": {

  "Key_1": {
    "Sub_Key_1": 160,
    "Sub_Key_2": 144,
    "Sub_Key_3": 304
  },
  "Key_2": {
    "Sub_Key_1": 140,
    "Sub_Key_2": 112,
    "Sub_Key_3": 252
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Set_1 = {
    "Key_1": {
        "Sub_Key_1": 110,
        "Sub_Key_2": 72,
        "Sub_Key_3": 182
    },
    "Key_2": {
        "Sub_Key_1": 110,
        "Sub_Key_2": 72,
        "Sub_Key_3": 182
    }
};

const Set_2 = {
    "Key_1": {
        "Sub_Key_1": 50,
        "Sub_Key_2": 72,
        "Sub_Key_3": 112
    },
    "Key_2": {
        "Sub_Key_1": 30,
        "Sub_Key_2": 40,
        "Sub_Key_3": 70
    }
};

const addSetsByKeys = (set1, set2) => {
    const output = {};

    Object.keys(set1).forEach(set1Key => {
        output[set1Key] = { ...set1[set1Key] };
    });

    Object.keys(set2).forEach(set2Key => {
        output[set2Key] = output[set2Key] || {};
        Object.keys(set2[set2Key]).forEach(set2SubKey => {
            output[set2Key][set2SubKey] = set2[set2Key][set2SubKey] + (output[set2Key][set2SubKey] || 0);
        });
    });

    return output;
}

const result = addSetsByKeys(Set_1, Set_2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the script based on the edited structure ?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra What do you mean by script ?, isn’t above code solving your issue ?

Comment: It is okay but my response structure is changed and when I am trying your code it is giving error. I have updated my structure in my question. Please help me on that. 

Thanks in advance and I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra From next time onwards please show your efforts to solve a problem if you post on stackoverflow.